# Django-Background-Tasks: Initialize Task at midnight and repeat every midnight

Tags: python, django

Good day SO,

I am currently using Django, and the Django-Background-Tasks package. I have a periodic task that I need to run at midnight, and it is to be repeated every midnight.

I am a beginner at using the package, and am confused by the following:

- How do I set the repeat parameter during initialization?

Here is my code:

```
from background_task import background
from datetime import datetime, date

today_date = datetime.datetime.today()
today_midnight = today_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)

@background(schedule=today_midnight)
def send_reminders():...
send_reminders(repeat=Task.DAILY)
```

I wanted to set the parameter 'repeat' to task.DAILY, as stated in the documentation. However, I have encountered the following:

```
NameError: name 'Task' is not defined
```

I know I have to import something to define Task, but I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is defined in the [**`background_task.models`** module [GitHub]](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/blob/6dd7772/background_task/models.py). So you should import this with:

```
from background_task.models import Task
```

[**`DAILY`**](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/blob/6dd7772/background_task/models.py#L150) itself just specifies the number of seconds, so *24×60×60=86'400*:

> ```
> class Task(models.Model):
>
>     # ...
>
>     HOURLY = 3600
>     DAILY = 24 * HOURLY
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply :) I didn't know where to look in the docs for the definitions, thanks for the help!